# linuxのデバイスドライバを作成するとき、ソースを/proc以下に入れればビルドなしで機能するのでしょうか。

Tags: linux, build

それとも、カーネルのソースコードに組み込んだあと、makeビルドしなくてはしなくてはいけないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make が必要です。
恐らく大抵の場合、/usr/src/linux 配下のカーネルソースにパッチを当てて make することになるでしょう (ドライバのソースコードの差分が手元にあるのであれば)。

/proc (や /sys) は今動作しているカーネルと情報のやり取りをすることはできても、デバイスドライバを作成する役には立ちません。